# Totaling several data points

Tags: ios

I'm working on an iOS app that takes data input from 16 text fields and outputs a calculated numerical total to a corresponding label.

What I'm looking to do now is add another label that totals all 16 of those numerical outputs into a single number. Each individual calculation works fine and outputs an accurate number, I just cannot even begin to know where to start coding a new label that Totals the values from the 16 other labels.

I'm not even sure I know how to word what I'm looking to do correctly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think in terms of "having a label that totals the values". That's confusing your *view* and your *model*. Your data shouldn't be held in your labels, they are just being used to display it.

You should have some structure like an array, held as part of your view controller, that holds the input values, and another one that holds the output values. If this is an `NSArray` of `NSNumber` objects, you can then get the sum as follows:

```
NSNumber* sum = [numbers valueForKeyPath: @"@sum.self"];
```

Where `numbers` is your array of numbers.

If you *do* want to do it directly from the labels, then you'll need to work through each label and get `[label.text integerValue]` and add them up.